# Add a custom parser for QWeb report

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I've tried to create a custom parser for my qweb report based on some tutorials on the internet:

ig_account_object_printout_report_parser.py

```
import time
from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class ig_account_object_printout_report_parser(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context): 
    super(ig_account_object_printout_report_parser, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
    self.localcontext.update({
        'time': time,
        'hello_world': self._hello_world,
    })

    def _hello_world(self, field):
        return "Hello World!"

class ig_account_object_report(osv.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'ig_account.ig_account_object_printout_report_template'
    _inherit = 'report.abstract_report'
    _template = 'ig_account.ig_account_object_printout_report_template'
    _wrapped_report_class = ig_account_object_printout_report_parser
```

ig_account_object_printout_report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <report 
            id="ig_account_object_printout"
            model="ig.account.object"
            string="Print Account Object"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="ig_account.ig_account_object_printout_report_template"
            attachment_use="False"
            file="ig_account.ig_account_object_printout_report_template"
        />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

ig_account_object_printout_report_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data> 
<template id="ig_account_object_printout_report_template">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <div class="page">                   
                <span t-esc="hello_world()"/>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

I need the custom parser because without it I won't be able to call python function to process some data.

But when I tried to run the report it returns:

```
QWebException: "'NoneType' object is not callable" while evaluating
'hello_world()'
```

I've included `ig_account_object_printout_report_parser.py` in the `__init__.py`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the method argument while you are calling the method in Qweb View.

```
def _hello_world(self, field):
    return "Hello World!"
```

the above function uses some argument as field but you can try to called that function something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data> 
<template id="ig_account_object_printout_report_template">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <div class="page">                   
                <span t-esc="hello_world(o.some_field_name)"/>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

you can check with upgrade your module and try to print the report again

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I missed that!! Thank you! What the hell is wrong with the error message it is so misleading!